# Different cakephp datasource for local and live

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My MySQL connection details are different for both my local connection and my deployed live hosted. I am using CakePHP 3

At the moment I have to keep changing the default datasource which is not really the best way to do it.

I have not added two datasources but I am not sure how to switch between them?

```
'Datasources' => [
    'development' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => '8889',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'local',
    ],
    'deployment' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'live_database',
    ],
```

Comment: Are you asking how to change the datasource from within your code or are you asking how to determine if you code is running in production or in local mode?

Comment: more like changing a value in the app.php something like for `'debug' => true`. Something like `datasource => 'deployment'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In boostrap or in App Controller, paste this

`if(Configure::read('debug')){
ConnectionManager::config('deployment');
}`

this change the default config of database when the debug is true.